# Excel - Populate multiple cells based on another cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the below table on the excel

```
     A           B         C         D
Total Errors   Error_1   Error_2   Error_3
     3
     2
     1
```

need a formula to populate cells from B:D as shown below.
**The output to be**:

```
     A           B         C         D
Total Errors   Error_1   Error_2   Error_3
     3           1         1         1
     2           1         1
     1           1
```

Thanks.

Comment: What if we have 4 in column A? What should B,C and D have then?

Comment: B    C   D   E 
1    1    1    1

Answer (score 0):

In **B2** enter:

```
=IF($A2>COLUMN()-2,1,"")
```

then copy this cell both across and down.

[image]